# RegEx for splitting Float in spans with corresponding classes

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a float e.g. 1377.5 that I want to be splitted with plain JavaScript in this structure:

```
<span class="digitLarge digit1">1</span>
<span class="digitLarge digit3">3</span>
<span class="digitLarge digit7">7</span>
<span class="digitLarge digit7">7</span>
<span class="digitPoint">.</span>
<span class="digitSmall digit5">5</span>
<span class="digitSmall digit0">0</span>
```

I tried with something like:

```
parseFloat(myFloat).toFixed(2).replace(/(.*)/g,'$1');
```

But here I cannot split in before point = Large and after point = Small. I could surely add multiple RegExes but this is kind of inconvenient...

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank You!

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
var number = 1377.50;
var splitted = String(number).split(".");
var beforePoint = splitted[0];
var afterPoint = splitted[0];
```

After that:

```
for(var i=0; i<beforePoint.length; i++){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML=beforePoint[i];
    span.className="myClass";
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}

var pointSpan = document.createElemnt("span");
pointSpan.innerHTML=".";
pointSpan.className="myClass";
document.body.appendChild(pointSpan);

 for(var i=0; i<afterPoint.length; i++){
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML=afterPoint[i];
    span.className="myClass";
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the `float` into the number and decimal like this:

```js
var a = 12345.67;
var lg = a.toString().split(".")[0]; ///before
var sm = a.toString().split(".")[1]; ///after
alert("large: " + lg + " small: " + sm);
//if you want to further split large
alert(lg.split(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myFloat = 1377.5,
    html    = '',
    dotReached = false;
    
myFloat = parseFloat(myFloat).toFixed(2);

for (var i = 0, l = myFloat.length; i < l; i++) {
    if ('.' === myFloat[i]) {
         html += '<span class="digitPoint">.</span>';
         dotReached = true;
         continue;
    }
    
    html += '<span class="' + (dotReached ? 'digitSmall' : 'digitLarge') + ' digit' + myFloat[i] + '">' + myFloat[i] + '</span>'
    
}

console.info(html);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replys, they all work but smarber's answer is my favourite one. Very neat.